# I have a question about statistics

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I do my practice and I stuck with this question

> Let $X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_9$ represent a  random sample from the distribution of $X$. What is the distribution of the sample $\dfrac{\sum_{i = 1}^9 X_i - 18}{15}$? Find $\mathbb P\left[\dfrac{\sum_{i = 1}^9 X_i - 18}{15}< 2\right]$.

and it gives additional information is "Let $X$ is normally distributed with mean $2$ and variance $25$". I try to find out what type of this distribution. it's not chi-square, normal. Can someone help me to solve this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** This is very elementary. You should know that

$$\sum_i (a_i\mathcal{N}(\mu_i,\sigma^2_i) + b_i) = \mathcal{N}\left(\sum_i (a_i\mu_i + b_i),\sum_i a^2_i\sigma_i^2\right)$$

Comment: Wow thank you, I figure out it. It's very elementary. This is a sample distribution of sample mean.

Comment: Good. You should take a few minutes and learn how to write this up in MathJax. It's not terribly difficult and will be very helpful for you in the future.